# Sections inside included blade templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to be able to add as many widgets as i want to a page.
To make it easier to visualize, here is what i want to achieve:

- Master Page

  - Regular Page

In regular page, i want to call blade template **panel** as many times as i want. Of course, i would like to change sections inside each panel too.

**Master Page**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">@yield('title')</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @yield('panelsLeft')
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-8 -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @yield('panelsRight')
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

**Panel Partial**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <i class="fa fa-{{ $panelIcon }} fa-fw"></i> @yield('panelTitle')

        <div class="pull-right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                @yield('panelActions')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
    <div class="panel-body">
        @yield('panelBody')
    </div>
    <!-- /.panel-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.panel -->
```

**Regular Page**
*I want my regular page to extend master page, include as many panels as needed, and set sections of each of them. How can i achieve this?*

I couldn't find an answer to this problem. Here is what i tried but it doesn't work:

```
@extends('layouts.content')
@section('title')
    Dashboard
@stop
@section('panelsLeft')

    @include('layouts.partial.panel', ['panelIcon'=>'flag'])
      @section('panelTitle')
        Current Projects
      @stop
      @section('panelActions')
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Create New Project
        </button>
      @stop
      @section('panelBody')
        <ul class="project-list">
          {{ $projects }}
        </ul>
      @stop

    @include('layouts.partial.panel', ['panelIcon'=>'user'])
      @section('panelTitle')
        Current Users
      @stop
      @section('panelActions')
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Create New User
        </button>
      @stop
      @section('panelBody')
        <ul class="user-list">
          {{ $users }}
        </ul>
      @stop
@stop
```

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840775/how-to-reuse-a-blade-partial-in-a-template). Or if not may be just try this package blade [partials](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/crhayes/blade-partials)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i had already solved my problem by putting '@include' below the '@section's. But your comment showed that this question is a duplicate actually. And the package you showed looks great. Thanks again.

Comment: Agreed that the question seems a duplicate, although the OP on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840775/how-to-reuse-a-blade-partial-in-a-template) hasn't accepted an answer. Flagged this as duplicate.