# How to make one word univeral variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, global-variables

I do not know if it is logical or not,

I want to make a varibale say **@ads** in **view** files
wherever I put **@ads**

It would call specific div element:

```
<div class="ads">
@if(condition)
 some block of codes...
@endif
</div>
```

which is defined for @ads.
is it possible? if yes how?

Comment: follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840775/how-to-reuse-a-blade-partial-in-a-template

Comment: @riya You can also create Laravel Directives for this purpose

Comment: please explain more

Comment: @Shaniawan What I did, added a file ads.blade.php with my div elements and called it by @includes('ads'). But is there any simpler way than this?

Comment: @riya there is a proper way for this.Create directive for this.
please follow this tutorial for creation of directives https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-custom-blade-directive-in-laravelexample.html

Comment: You can follow this link to create custom blade directives https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-about-writing-custom-blade-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're free to use the [@include](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews) directive :

```
@if(condition)
    @include('ads')
@endif
```

It will include the blade view from `ads.blade.php`